# RSpec spy match_array on hash value

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple test in an RSpec controller spec that checks to see if the correct message was passed to a delayed job:

```
it 'sends a message to NotifyFollowersJob with relevant person and split_time data' do
  allow(NotifyFollowersJob).to receive(:perform_later)
  post :import, params: request_params
  split_time_ids = SplitTime.all.ids
  person_id = SplitTime.first.effort.person_id

  expect(NotifyFollowersJob).to have_received(:perform_later)
                                        .with(person_id: person_id,
                                              split_time_ids: split_time_ids)
end
```

The test usually passes, but sometimes it fails because the `split_time_ids` (an Array) are sometimes reversed. I do not care what order the `split_time_ids` are passed to NotifyFollowersJob, so the test should pass regardless of the order.

If I were testing the contents of the Array alone, I could write:

```
expect(split_time_ids).to match_array(SplitTime.all.ids)
```

But I can't figure out how to get similar functionality where the Array is a value of one of several arguments.

Any RSpec masters out there care to give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to make a block to check the message and pass it to your `allow` method.

Like this:

```
allow(NotifyFollowersJob).to receive(:perform_later) do |arg|
  # Handle your args to avoid fails because of its order
  expect(...)
end
```

And you should keep the `expect(NotifyFollowersJob).to have_received(:perform_later)` (without the `with` verification) just to make sure it is still being called.

Comment: This turned me on to a solution. I used your technique and within the block I added `args[:split_time_ids].sort!`. I retained the `with` verification but changed it to `with(person_id: person_id, split_time_ids: split_time_ids.sort)`. If you'd like to incorporate that into your answer I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I don't think the block after allow() runs!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your controller action runs `SplitTime.all.ids` query and passes them to the worker as args.

If you don't care about the order, maybe you can stub this query, to get the same result all the time?
In addition, it'll make your test faster.

Comment: That's a good thought. Unfortunately, the POST /import action imports records of one type and creates new records of a different type, so I would have no way of knowing what ids were in fact passed to the worker.

Comment: But if controller contains such logic, then you can extract it into a separate method and stub the whole method. WDYT?

Comment: The logic that does this is contained within an ETL module and covers 4-5 classes. It would be difficult to extract. Also, this is a controller test for an API, so I think of it as a full integration test, and I'm trying to keep stubbing to a minimum. I would much prefer just to know how to match the arguments.

Comment: Then the point is that you have the too heavy controller. Controller's responsibility is just to receive params, run corresponding services/operations classes and render response. So It looks like you have your business logic in wrong place if it's so hard to test it.

Comment: None of the logic is in the controller. It's in the ETL module. This is an integration test and I don't want to stub anything.